# plot line behind barplot

Tags: r, plot

I would like to create a barplot where the bars are plotted on top of the horizontal line.

The following code accomplishes this:

```
y <- c(1,2,3,5)
barplot(y)
abline(h=mean(y))
barplot(y, add=T)
```

However, I'm concerned that the `add=T` parameter in `barplot()`, if used repeatedly, can introduce printing artifacts.  I'm curious if there's an alternative to the above code (though the above code may be the fastest method).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could just plot nothing in your first call:

```
y <- c(1,2,3,5)
barplot(
  rep(NA, length(y)),
  ylim = pmax(range(y), 0),
  axes = FALSE
)
abline(h = mean(y))
barplot(y, add = TRUE)
```

[image: Barplot with horizontal line behind the bars, as desired]

Comment: i hate that `plot(barplot(..., plot=FALSE))` doesn't "just work". feels extra clunky to invoke the `barplot()` code twice.

Answer (score 9):

If you use ggplot2, you don't have to worry about this. Your problem boils down to the geom order:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:4, y=y), aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=mean(y), color="red")
```

[image: line in front]

In comparison:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:4, y=y), aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=mean(y), color="red") +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: line behind]

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to know.  I should give `ggplot2` another look.