# ggplot2: plotting line behind boxplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot a line using geom_line **behind** my boxplot, I finally managed to combine line plotting with a boxplot. I have this dataset which I used to create a boxplot:

```
>head(MdataNa)

            1           2           3           4           5           6           7
1 -0.02798634 -0.05740014 -0.02643664  0.02203644  0.02366325 -0.02868668 -0.01278713
2  0.20278229  0.19960302  0.10896017  0.24215229  0.31925211  0.29928739  0.15911725
3  0.06570653  0.08658396 -0.06019098  0.01437147  0.02078022  0.13814853  0.11369999
4 -0.42805441 -0.91945721 -1.05555731 -0.90877542 -0.77493682 -0.90620917 -1.00535742
5  0.39922939  0.12347996  0.06712451  0.07419287 -0.09517628 -0.12056720 -0.40863078
6  0.52821596  0.30827515  0.29733794  0.30555717  0.31636676  0.11592717  0.16957927
```

I have glucose concentration which should be plotted in a line behind this boxplot:

```
# glucose curve values
require("scales")
offconc <- c(0,0.4,0.8,1.8,3.5,6.9,7.3)
offtime <- c(9,11.4,12.9,14.9,16.7,18.3,20.5)

# now we have to scale them so they fit in the (boxplot)plot
time <- rescale(offtime, to=c(1,7))
conc <- rescale(offconc, to=c(-1,1))
glucoseConc <- data.frame(time,conc)
glucoseConc2 <- melt(glucoseConc, id = "time")
```

Then I plotted this data, but I was only able to plot the glucose curve in **FRONT** of the boxplot instead of behind it, I used this code:

```
boxNa <- ggplot(stack(MdataNa), aes(x = ind, y = values)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_cartesian(y = c(-1.5,1.5)) + 
  labs(list(title = "After Loess", x = "Timepoint", y = "M")) +
  geom_line(data=glucoseConc2,aes(x=time,y=value),group=1)
```

output of the code above:

[image: graph produced by the above code]

**EDIT as suggested by the comments(NOT WORKING)**

```
boxNa <- ggplot(stack(MdataNa), aes(x = ind, y = values)) +
  geom_line(data=glucoseConc2,aes(x=time,y=value),group=1) +
  geom_boxplot(data=stack(MdataNa), aes(x = ind, y = values)) + 
  coord_cartesian(y = c(-1.5,1.5)) + 
  labs(list(title = "After Loess", x = "Timepoint", y = "M"))
```

this will give the following error:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

*probably I'm doing something wrong then?*

Comment: Rearrange so `geom_boxplot` is called after `geom_line.`

Comment: I tried that but that will give this error: " Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" I will paste that code in my question

Comment: That means you're supplying the wrong type of data to `geom_line`. Maybe try emptying out the `ggplot` call, as everything is getting specified in the geom anyway. The concept does work: `library(tidyverse); mtcars %>% rownames_to_column('car') %>% gather(var, val, -car) %>% group_by(var) %>% mutate(mean_val = mean(val)) %>% ggplot(aes(var, val)) + geom_line(aes(var, mean_val), group = 1) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597543/plot-line-behind-barplot

Comment: I've found  an solution, but not so elegant: just add `geom_boxplot() +` again at the bottom of `geom_line` line. It worked.

Comment: that question is about a regular plot not about ggplo2 @pat-s

Comment: to the original code(first paste of my code) or the code which was edited after the comments? @Peter.k

Comment: Wow thankyou @Peter.k I have been trying to figure this out for the whole day....

Comment: @user7384813 See the second answer in the question I linked (addressing ggplot2)

Comment: @timat the main problem is the order of the plot commands. If one uses `geom_boxplot` or `geom_bar`does not make a difference. A quick search would also have helped here as this is a basic question. Don't mean to be rude - just keep SO tidy :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plot line behind barplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597543/plot-line-behind-barplot)

Comment: @stibu I don't think this is a dup. The other Q is about base plot, not `ggplot2`. And the `ggplot2` answers there deal with adding a simple `geom_hline` which doesn't address the issues here. Perhaps, there is another dup but this not a good one.

Comment: @Stibu I won't consider as a duplicates as putting geom line first is raising another problem regarding applying discrete values on a continuous scale.

Comment: @pat-s I don't think this is a dup. The `ggplot2` answers there deal with adding a simple `geom_hline` which doesn't address the issues here. Perhaps, there is another dup but this not a good one.

Comment: @user7384813 can you mark the answer as resolved if it works? (click grey check under the downvoting arrow)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.
The idea is to convert the x axis in continous values:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=glucoseConc2,aes(x=time,y=value),group=1)+
  geom_boxplot(data=stack(MdataNA), aes(x = as.numeric(ind), y = values, group=ind)) + 
  coord_cartesian(y = c(-1.5,1.5)) + 
  labs(list(title = "After Loess", x = "Timepoint", y = "M"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:7)
```

Comment: @user7384813 if it works you might consider to mark it as resolved